# React strict mode and double rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Having such a simple CRA `React` app:

*./index.tsx:*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <Home></Home>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*./components/Home.tsx:*

```
function Home() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        
        let x = 0;
        console.log("--> inside a Promise obj <--");
        
        if (x === 0) {
            myResolve("OK");
        } else {
            myReject("Error");
        }
    }); 

    myPromise.then(
        function(value) {console.log("--> Promise fulfilled <--")},
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <b>Home Page</b>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

I'm getting:

```
--> inside a Promise obj <--
--> Promise fulfilled <--
--> Promise fulfilled <--
```

on the console.

Why does the *Promise* fulfilled code is triggered 2 times? I know, that for *React Strict* mode the component is rendered twice but the example show some inconsistency here - the `--> inside a Promise obj <--` message is called ONE time while the `--> Promise fulfilled <--` TWICE! although both messages is being printed in the same function!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html):-

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in
> certain cases where a workaround can be used.

As a temporary workaround you can just do `let log = console.log` at the top level and then it'll always log.

Got this workaround from - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20090

Here is a code sandbox where you can see the expected output :-

[image: Edit strict-mode-react logging]

The **logging** inside the `then` callback of the promise works because it's an async behavior outside the **lifecycle** methods of React. React doesn't silence those **logs** in **Strict Mode**.
But the `console.log("inside a Promise obj")` is a synchronous task happening inside the `Promise` executor function which happens during the execution of your component's **function body**.

Comment: Ok, thx i know this docs statement about the silencing log massages. But if it silence the `--> inside a Promise obj <--` why it doesn't silence the `--> Promise fulfilled <--` for printing twice!? This is my real question friend!